# Testing if a python object has written documentation

Tags: python, unit-testing, documentation, decorator

## Some context

Im writing a Python application and I want to guarantee that no one forgets to write documentation for the classes, modules and public functions/methods. For that I created an unit test and, for the sake of the question, the assertion part is like the following (the filtering part of what needs to be tested is more complex and I avoided putting it here):

```
...
assertIsNotNone(item.__doc__, msg="%s has no documentation" % name(item))
assertGreaterEqual(len(item.__doc__.strip()), 10, msg="%s should have more documentation" % name(item))
...
```

The `name(item)` is just an auxiliary function that returns a proper name for the object being checked

## The problem

Not all my functions or classes actually needs documentation (like the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods in a unit test). In those cases I want to make explicit that no documentation will be written for the item in question. The goal of my unit test is to check if any documentation was forgotten, so the test should skip those cases

## My solution

I wrote the following decorator to be applied on those cases:

```
import inspect

def no_doc(item):
    """
    Decorator that makes explicit that the function/method 
    or class in question has no documentation 
    """

    result = None

    if inspect.isclass(item):
        class wrapper (item):
            "Class intentionally with no documentation"
            pass

        result = wrapper

    elif inspect.isfunction(item):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            "Function intentionally with no documentation"
            return item(*args, **kwargs)

        result = wrapper

    return result
```

### Concerns

As the goal of the decorator it to only change the **doc** string and nothing more, my decorated functions/methods/classes has to keep their behavior as much as possible. I fear that decorating them with `@no_doc` to solve a development problem can induce bugs or behavior changes into production code.

## Finally, the question

I ask you if my decorator approach is a good approach to solve the problem and if the decorator itself is implemented safely

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have any major problems with what you have there (that I can think of).  However, you can avoid the new subclasses / functions by explicitly modifying `__doc__`:

```
def no_doc(item):
    """A decorator to add the no-doc docstring
     objects that don't need any other documentation"""

    t = "class" if inspect.isclass(item) else "function"
    item.__doc__ = "This {} intentionally has no documentation".format(t)

    return item
```

Doing this ensures that you get the exact same type (for classes) and the exact same function signature for functions and avoid any problems that either of those cases might cause.

Comment: That is simple and nice, and was my first implementation. The problem is when you try to decorate a class with it you get a `AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'type' objects is not writable`. Doing some basic scripting it is indeed not possible to change a class `__doc__` string, event if it is an user class